# Passing values between jQuery and Controller Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Quite a bit of links, but I can't piece all of the info together.

I assume a controller, a view and routes are involved.

Regarding the url and routes, I have the generic folder structure, app/views/pages/home and app/controllers/pages_controller.rb. Can you guide me if I'm doing the routing and url correctly, also?

routes.rb

```
get pages/get_aj //Don't know if this is what you put
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'get'
url: '/pages/get_aj' //can someone confirm this is how you do it? 
dataType: "JSON" //I need to pass back values from the controller to JS. Do I use JSON?
}).success(function(data){
      alert("returned " + data);
});

//some other jQuery code that will depend on the data returned.
```

pages_controller.rb

```
def get_aj
   respond_to do |format|
      format.json{render :json => "we got here" } //Do I return .js?
   end
end
```

rake routes

```
   pages_home GET /pages/home(.:format)    pages#home
pages_contact GET /pages/contact(.:format) pages#contact
 pages_get_aj GET /pages/get_aj(.:format)  pages#get_aj
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Being generic - it doesn't work. I was looking for confirmation, maybe I am overlooking some detail, because it does not return a value. I don't know even if it properly goes to rails.

Comment: in your controller change `format.json` to `format.js` and post your `rake routes` regarding the pages_controller and the console message

Comment: Editted the question with routes. and do I change both format.js and js=> "we got here"?

Comment: just replace the `format.js`, also what does the console in your browser say?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it is passing values back and forth now. I was able to get the alert(data), but it is all [Object object].

Comment: What was the point of replacing .json to .js? The result is the same

Comment: you are getting a json object, you need to access it's properties, just post your console result here, using `js` to respond to an ajax call, if you want to use `json` add `contentType: 'application/json'` to your ajax call or use `getJSON`

Comment: Started GET "/pages/get_aj?ticker=CLL" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-19 12:24:05 -0400
Processing by PagesController#get_aj as JSON
  Parameters: {"ticker"=>"CLL"}
  BBOrder Load (120.7ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [dbo].[BBOrders].* FROM [dbo].[BBOrders] WHERE (symbol LIKE N''%CLL%'')'
Completed 200 OK in 429ms (Views: 287.2ms | ActiveRecord: 120.7ms)
This is all there is for that call. I decided to pass a parameter to test. It does pass it. I don't see how this console call call help you.

Comment: If you alert({this:"that"}) it will always be [object object]. Alert needs strings. Use console.log to inspect an object instead.

Comment: not the rails console, [your browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: See example: http://jsfiddle.net/YNeA3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should work actually. The biggest thing you're misunderstanding is what JS alert does. It alerts strings, and `data` is an object. See this JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YNeA3/

To inspect objects from JS, use `console.log()` instead of alert. These will show up in your browser console. This is the basic bread and butter debugging tool for JS.

I'm not sure what the JSON object you're sending looks like, because you should be rendering a hash, not a string. That's the only real problem with your code, I think.

Also, a suggestion: if this controller action is only going to be for ajax you don't have to bother with the respond_to block. I would specify status though.

```
def get_aj
  data = {:message => "Alert this!"}
  render :json => data, :status => :ok
end
```

Now in your JS:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/pages/get_aj',
  success: function(data,status,xhr){
    console.log(data);
    alert(data.message);
  },
  error: function(xhr,status,error){
    console.log(xhr);
    alert(error);
  }
});
```

Data will be a JS object looking just like the hash you sent.

Comment: Kudos for the console.log()!